# plot interaction between two predictors (lme4) with plotLMER.fnc

Tags: r, lme4

I'm trying to plot the interaction between "condition" and "snarc_num" in the model (built with lme4 package):

```
quant_num<-lmer(response_time1~condition*snarc_num+(1+condition|subject_nr) + (1|couple), data=quant_slopes)
```

To plot the interaction I should use the plotLMER.fnc from the languageR package, and I tried:

```
plotLMER.fnc(quant_num, xlabel = "snarc_num", ylabel ="RTs", ylimit = c(6.5,7.5), 
              fun = NA, pred = "snarc_num", control =list(quant_slopes$condition, quant_slopes$snarc_num), ranefs = NA, n = 100, 
             intr =list("condition","snarc_num"),  lockYlim = TRUE, addlines = TRUE, 
             withList = FALSE, cexsize = 0.5, linecolor = 2, addToExistingPlot = FALSE, 
             verbose = TRUE)
```

but it doesn't work.
Could anyone help me with this plot?

Thank you!

Comment: `but it doesn't work`. What doesn't work? Are you getting an error? A plot you believe to be erroneous? What does your data look like? We need more in this question.

Comment: I get an error: Error in intr[[3]] : index out of limit. In my data I have the condition (congruent or incongruent), Response times and the "snarc_num" which is a value assigned to each subject (46 subjects in total). So what I need is a plot of the model that i attached in my question to show the interaction (which is significant) between the condition and the snarc_num in predicting response times (alreaady log-transformed).  I hope to have added all the needed details. Thank you